# Spring Bean Constructor Fails to set POJO Properties

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, constructor, autowired

I am trying to create a spring bean from my main method.

I have configured this bean to have *specific* properties.  These values were specified within a SpringConfig class annotated by @Configuration.

The bean is created inside my main() method using a Spring Application Context.  The bean launches successfully but it does not have the properties I had specified in my SpringConfig class.  I can't understand why?

I may have identified the cause of the problem:  The POJO class for this bean uses @Autowired and @Qualifier to field-inject a different set of properties and it is *these* values which persist when I create the bean (using Spring Context from my main method).

I cannot understand why I can't overwrite these field injections by calling a parameterised constructor from my SpringConfig class.

Weirdly, I *can* explicitly mutate the properties to what I need them to be from my main method (ie `myBean.setproperty(NewVal)` works).  Why does that work but `new MyBean(OtherVal)` fail?  That makes no sense!

Here is my code

App.java:

```
package com.qa;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

import com.qa.beans.AutoWiredBean;
import com.qa.beans.Book;
import com.qa.beans.Owner;

public class App {
    private ApplicationContext context;


// Constructor...
public App() {
    context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfig.class);

    Owner owner1 = (Owner) context.getBean("ownerBean");
    Book myBook = (Book) context.getBean("bookBean");
    AutoWiredBean myAWBean = (AutoWiredBean) context.getBean("autoWiredBean_Bean");
    AutoWiredBean myAWBean2 = (AutoWiredBean) context.getBean("autoWiredBean_Bean2");

    System.out.println("\n" + owner1);
    System.out.println("\n" + myBook);
    System.out.println("\n" + myAWBean);
    System.out.println("\n" + myAWBean2);  //Observe:  Spring fails to accept property parameters specified in the SpringConfig class.  Yet Spring WILL accept a mutation request (eg: myAWBean2.setName="Tessa") as done so below. 

    myAWBean2.setName("Tessa"); myAWBean2.setId(27);  //This works, but line 25 above does not. Line 25 uses SpringConfig class to set properties via constructor. WEIRD!!!!
    System.out.println("\n" + myAWBean2);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new App();
    }
}
```

Here is the SpringConfig class:

```
package com.qa;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

import com.qa.beans.AutoWiredBean;
import com.qa.beans.Book;
import com.qa.beans.Owner;
import com.qa.beans.Pet;


@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:Bean.properties")  
public class SpringConfig {

@Bean
public AutoWiredBean autoWiredBean_Bean(){
    return new AutoWiredBean();
}

@Bean
public AutoWiredBean autoWiredBean_Bean2(){
    return new AutoWiredBean(nameBean(), idBean());
}

@Bean
public String nameBean(){
    return "Iqbal Hamid";
}

@Bean
public String name2Bean(){
    return "Elouise McDermot";
}

@Bean
public String name3Bean(){
    return "Tony Apsley";
}

@Bean
public String name4Bean(){
    return "Luke Skywalker";
}

@Bean
public int idBean() {
    return 50;
}

@Bean
public int id2Bean() {
    return 37;
}

@Bean
public int id3Bean() {
    return 33;
}

@Bean
public int id4Bean() {
    return 44;
}


@Value("${book.author}") String name;
@Value("${book.title}") String title;
@Bean
public Book bookBean () {
    return new Book (title, name);
}

@Bean
public Pet pet1Bean() {
    Pet pet = new Pet();
    pet.setName("Daisy");
    return pet;
}

@Bean
Pet pet2Bean() {
    return new Pet("Lola");
}

@Bean
Pet pet3Bean() {
    return new Pet("Fido");
}


@Bean
public Owner ownerBean(){
    ArrayList<Pet> petList = new ArrayList<Pet>();

    petList.add(pet1Bean());
    petList.add(pet2Bean());
    petList.add(pet3Bean());

    return new Owner("Lina", petList);
    }
}
```

Here is the problematic POJO :

```
package com.qa.beans;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;

@Scope("prototype")
public class AutoWiredBean implements InitializingBean, DisposableBean  {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("name2Bean")
private String name;

@Autowired
@Qualifier ("id2Bean")
private int id;


// No arg constructor...
public AutoWiredBean() {
    super();
}

// Parameterised constructor...
@Autowired
public AutoWiredBean(String name, int id) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "AutoWiredBean Details: Name = '" + name + "', ID = " + id;
}

@Override
public void destroy() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Destroying AWBbean!");
}

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Set Property of AWBbean!");     
    }
}
```

Comment: Because there are multiple matching things in configuration that have type `String`, for example, and your constructor doesn't specify which one of those it wants to be autowired. That's judging by what `AutoWiredBean` looks like.

Comment: I do specify which beans the construct should use.  This is don in my SpringConfig classfile.  The relevant code is:


`@Bean
public AutoWiredBean autoWiredBean_Bean2(){
    return new AutoWiredBean(nameBean(), idBean());
}`

Comment: And you're saying that a bean created like that doesn't have any of its properties set?

Answer (score 1):

This is because when a Spring bean is instantiated, it is assembled in a certain order:

1. **First:** The constructor executes;
2. **Second:** Dependencies are injected;
3. **Third:** Initialisation hooks are executed;

Normally, in a class, you would place your class initialisation code inside the constructor.

However, if your class depends upon any field-injected properties and you wish to use these to initialise your class, you cannot do that inside a constructor.  This is because those injections do not take place until *after* the constructor has executed!

So for example you may have some class-scope variables which have been injected with a value from a properties files (via @Value) or it may have been injected with a bean (via @Autowired) and you wish to populate an array, you must do this inside your initialisation hook and not inside a constructor.

Therefore, I presume constructor injections are being overridden above by field injections as a result of the order of the stages of a bean's life-cycle as managed by the Spring container.

```
package SpringDemo_Annotations;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;


@Component("fortuneService_FileProperties")
public class FortuneService_FileProperties implements IFortuneService {

    @Value("${fortune1}")
    private String fortune1;

    @Value("${fortune2}")
    private String fortune2;

    @Value("${fortune3}")
    private String fortune3;

    @Value("${fortune4}")
    private String fortune4;

    @Value("${fortune5}")
    private String fortune5;

    private ArrayList<String> arrFortunes;


    // Constructor...
    public FortuneService_FileProperties() {
        System.out.println("\nOBSERVE: Order of the lifestages of a bean:\tFIRST we enter the constructor:\t\t INSIDE FortuneService_FileProperties Constructor!");

        //
        // NOTE:  
        // YOU CANNOT PLACE CODE INSIDE THE CONSTRUCTOR WHICH REFERENCES FIELD INJECTED BEANS (via @Autowired) OR FIELD INJECTED VALUES (via @Value)
        // BECAUSE THEY DO NOT GET INJECTED UNTIL AFTER THE CONSTRUCTOR HAS EXECUTED!!!
        // THEREFORE CODE BELOW HAS BEEN SHIFTED OVER TO HOOKOBJECT_INITIALISE...
        //
//      arrFortunes = new ArrayList<String>();
//      
//      arrFortunes.add(this.fortune1);
//      arrFortunes.add(this.fortune2);
//      arrFortunes.add(this.fortune3);
//      arrFortunes.add(this.fortune4);
//      arrFortunes.add(this.fortune5);

        System.out.println("OBSERVE: Order of the lifestages of a bean:\tSECOND Field injections take place:");
    }


    // Getter...
    @Override
    public String getFortune() {
        return arrFortunes.get((int) (Math.random() * arrFortunes.size()));
    }


    @PostConstruct
    public void hookObject_Initialise() {
        System.out.println("OBSERVE: Order of the lifestages of a bean:\tTHIRD we enter the initialisation hook.  Fields have now been injected, so if we need to use field-injected beans or field-injected values, to conduct any initialisation (eg to populate an array), we do this here!:\tINSIDE FortuneService_FileProperties @PostConstruct!");

        //
        // THIS IS THE CORRECT PLACE TO INITIALISE ANY CLASS-SCOPE VARIABLES
        // WHICH ACCESS FIELD INJECTED PROPERTIES...
        //
        arrFortunes = new ArrayList<String>();

        arrFortunes.add(this.fortune1);
        arrFortunes.add(this.fortune2);
        arrFortunes.add(this.fortune3);
        arrFortunes.add(this.fortune4);
        arrFortunes.add(this.fortune5);
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void hookObject_Destroy() {
        System.out.println("\nOBSERVE: Order of the lifestages of a bean:\tFOURTH at destruction-time, we enter the destruction hook:\tINSIDE FortuneService_FileProperties() @PreDestoy!");
    }
}
```